# Determine file creation date in Java

Tags: java, date, filesystems

There is another similar question to mine on StackOverflow ([How to get creation date of a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741466/how-to-get-creation-date-of-a-file-in-java)), but the answer isn't really there as the OP had a different need that could be solved via other mechanisms.  I am trying to create a list of the files in a directory that can be sorted by age, hence the need for the file creation date.

I haven't located any good way to do this after much trawling of the web.  Is there a mechanism for getting file creation dates?

BTW, currently on a Windows system, may need this to work on a Linux system as well.  Also, I can't guarantee that a file naming convention would be followed where the creation date/time is embedded in the name.

Comment: Okay, after more discussions and investigations into the filesystems, we have decided that using last modified is sufficient since it would likely have to have been checked along with creation date.  Both would need to be checked to determine whether an old file was recently modified and therefore still active.  So, just check for the file modified farthest in the past.  Thanks for all the input.  BTW, I would love to use nio, but the Linux flavor here doesn't support file creation anyway.

Answer (score 202):

**Java nio** has options to access `creationTime` and other meta-data as long as the filesystem provides it.
Check [this link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) out

For example (provided based on [@ydaetskcoR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291321/ydaetskcor)'s comment):

```java
Path file = ...;
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);

System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
```

Comment: This would be best, but it is Java 7.  We are still using 6, but I will investigate our upgrade options.

Comment: use `readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class)` else you get: `no suitable method found for readAttributes(File,Class<BasicFileAttributes>)
    method Files.<A>readAttributes(Path,Class<A>,LinkOption...) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) A
        (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to Path))`

Comment: @Hooli No worries, mate! Try this https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/java/file-creation-date.html.

Comment: File creation date is not available on JDK 8 (at least) since `statx` syscall was added in newer Linux kernel version.

Comment: But why the creation time is always the same  as the last modified time?

Comment: Yep, very confusing but it seems that a call to get creationTime on Java will instead of complaining it doesnt exists just return the lastModifiedTime instead.

Answer (score 20):

I've solved this problem using JDK 7 with this code:

```
package FileCreationDate;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("c:\\1.txt");
        Path filePath = file.toPath();

        BasicFileAttributes attributes = null;
        try
        {
            attributes =
                    Files.readAttributes(filePath, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception handled when trying to get file " +
                    "attributes: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
        long milliseconds = attributes.creationTime().to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if((milliseconds > Long.MIN_VALUE) && (milliseconds < Long.MAX_VALUE))
        {
            Date creationDate =
                    new Date(attributes.creationTime().to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

            System.out.println("File " + filePath.toString() + " created " +
                    creationDate.getDate() + "/" +
                    (creationDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
                    (creationDate.getYear() + 1900));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

As a follow-up to this question - since it relates specifically to creation time and discusses obtaining it via the new nio classes - it seems right now in JDK7's implementation you're out of luck. Addendum: same behaviour is in OpenJDK7.

On Unix filesystems you cannot retrieve the creation timestamp, you simply get a copy of the last modification time. So sad, but unfortunately true. I'm not sure why that is but the code specifically does that as the following will demonstrate.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;

public class TestFA {
  static void getAttributes(String pathStr) throws IOException {
    Path p = Paths.get(pathStr);
    BasicFileAttributes view
       = Files.getFileAttributeView(p, BasicFileAttributeView.class)
              .readAttributes();
    System.out.println(view.creationTime()+" is the same as "+view.lastModifiedTime());
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for (String s : args) {
        getAttributes(s);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it for Android? BasicFileAttributes isn't available as built in API there...

Comment: This is indeed true, even a call to `stat` doesn't work. Unless you happen to run a kernel higher than 4.11 with glibc higher than 2.28, and coreutils higher than 8.31, then `stat` will report the _birth_ of the file. See related answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/birth-is-empty-on-ext4/50184#50184
Currently the JDK doesn't use statx syscal.

Answer (score 12):

The API of `java.io.File` only supports getting the last *modified* time. And the Internet is very quiet on this topic as well.

Unless I missed something significant, the Java library as is (up to but not yet including Java 7) does not include this capability. So if you were desperate for this, one solution would be to write some C(++) code to call system routines and call it using JNI. Most of this work seems to be already done for you in a library called [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/), though.

You may still need to do a little OS specific coding in Java for this, though, as you'll probably not find the same system calls available in Windows and Unix/Linux/BSD/OS X.

Comment: Yeah, Java 7 would be great as the nio appears to have this in basic attributes.  Never thought I would complain about being born too early!  ;)

Comment: The reason the `File` class doesn't have this capability is that most filesystems don't even track this information. And those that do don't always agree on when it should be updated.

Comment: @Syntactic: Actually [most filesystems do track this information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata). Exceptions include ext<=3 and Reiser. FAT, NTFS, HFS, ZFS, and ext4 support it. But it has been slow to propagate through all the layers of Linux and the libraries and commands to make it universally used.

Comment: @Carl In linux, I am getting modification and creation date as same while using Java NIO. Is it the normal behaviour?

Comment: @JayeshDhandha, if nothing modifies the file after it's created, I would *expect* creation and modification times to be equal. You could try changing that by using `touch` to change the mod time and then checking again.

Comment: @CarlSmotricz I just figure out that for some file system creation time is the same as the modification time, So We can say it's a limitation of the file system

Answer (score 12):

This is a basic example of how to get the creation date of a file in `Java`, using [**`BasicFileAttributes`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) class:

```
   Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\jorgesys\\workspaceJava\\myfile.txt");
    BasicFileAttributes attr;
    try {
    attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
    System.out.println("Creation date: " + attr.creationTime());
    //System.out.println("Last access date: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
    //System.out.println("Last modified date: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("oops error! " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: People looking to use this class should note that it started shipping in Java 1.7.

Answer (score 10):

On a Windows system, you can use free [FileTimes](http://mindprod.com/products1.html#FILETIMES) library.

This will be easier in the future with [Java NIO.2 (JDK 7) and the java.nio.file.attribute package](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/nio/#8).

But remember that most Linux filesystems [don't support file creation timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata).

Comment: Any other way around for linux machines which doesn't support created time ?

Comment: Just use a file system that does support file creation timestamps. The Wikipedia article linked suggests ext4 which is quite common now.

Answer (score 2):

in java1.7+ 
You can use this code to get file`s create time !

```java
private static LocalDateTime getCreateTime(File file) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(file.getPath());
        BasicFileAttributeView basicfile = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, BasicFileAttributeView.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
        BasicFileAttributes attr = basicfile.readAttributes();
        long date = attr.creationTime().toMillis();
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date);
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
```

Comment: could you please elaborate on why do we need this hustle with `Instant.ofEpochMilli(date)`. Thanks

Comment: @KirillKarmazin Since Java 1.8 we don't need to. We can directly use `Instant instant = attr.creationTime().toInstant();`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically after you get the creation date from the BasicFileAttributeView object, you should format the date to show:

```
String modifiedDate;
Path inPath = Paths.get(yourfile.getAbsolutePath());
BasicFileAttributes attr;
try {
    attr = Files.readAttributes(inPath, BasicFileAttributes.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    attr = null;
}
        
if (attr == null) {
     this.modifiedDate = null;
} else {
    this.modifiedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(attr.creationTime().toMillis());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Please don't teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. The `FileTime` object that you get from `creationTime()` has a `toInstant` method that gives you an `Instant` that you may convert to the desired time zone (for example `ZoneId.systemDefault()`) and format using a modern `DateTimeFormatter`. The resulting code will be a bit longer, which is an advantage since it is making more explicit what is happening and therefore reads more clearly and naturally.