# Determine file creation time in java

Tags: java, file, io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine file creation date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723838/determine-file-creation-date-in-java)

I have a file named `abc.txt` which is created by my application in `c:`. Now I have to write logic in such way
that if file is created within 1 hour timeframe then I have to print:

> file is created within 1 hour itself

and if file is created more than 1 hour before then to print the statement:

> It has been more then 1 hour the file is created

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723838/determine-file-creation-date-in-java

Cheers,

Comment: @AndersRostgaardBystrup could you please post the code so that I can grasp more

Comment: @user1726942 - your last comment is so funny! I hope you cite where you get the answer from - and i hope you trust the answer is correct. ;)

Answer (score 1):

[java.io.File.lastModified()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) should suit your needs.

Comment: @spOOm please post the code so that I can grasp

Comment: @user1726942 I think you could try by yourself. `lastModified()` returns *the time that the file denoted by this abstract pathname was last modified*. From that, writing an algorithm that checks whether the file has been modified during the last hour or not is not so hard.

Comment: @SpOOm thanks a lot for guiding, Bro I am stuck up thats why I need your advise ,Thanks a lot if possible then request you to please post the code..!!

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code

```
File f = new File("path of file");
Date now = new Date();
Date filedate = new Date(f.lastModified());
if((now.getTime()-filedate.getTime())>60000){
    System.out.println("It has been more then 1 hour the file is created");
}else{
    System.out.println("file is created within 1 hour itself");
}
```