# File creation time in OSX with Java 7

Tags: java, filesystems, timestamp, java-7

I need to get the creation time attribute of a file on OS X Lion. I have tried with **Java nio**, but it returns the modification time instead:

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);     
System.out.println("Creation time: " + attr.creationTime());
```

I have read similar questions ([Determine file creation date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723838/determine-file-creation-date-in-java)) and I know that some file systems don't support file creation timestamps but [HFSP does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata) so shouldn't BasicFileAttributes.creationTime method return the right value on OS X?

Comment: I asked in Oracle forums and it is a bug in Java 7. I submitted it to java 7 bug database.

Answer (score 0):

No sure why , but are you seeing the same time stamp for all of these :

```
System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
```

Comment: No, just for creationTime and lastModifiedTime.

Comment: When did you create the file ? Did you check the file attributes i.e creation time and modified time as soon as you created ?

Comment: I compare the result with the creation date shown by "ls -lU" command.