# how to read desktop folder and files.........my below program reading all the files (which are inside folder too)

Tags: java

i wish to read file + folder+ shortcut on desktop
with its created date and modified/last access date...so what changes should i made

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class read {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<File> fileList =new ArrayList();
    final File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\ROSH\\Desktop");
    new read().listFilesForFolder(folder, fileList);
}

public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder,List<File> fileList) {
    File[] filesInFolder = folder.listFiles();

    if (filesInFolder != null) {
        for (final File fileEntry : filesInFolder) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("DIR : "+fileEntry.getName());
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry,fileList);
            } else {
                System.out.println("FILE : "+fileEntry.getName());
                fileList.add(fileEntry);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Your program looks OK.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Roshan. Can you help us out by defining a specific problem with your code above? What excepted output do you wish to receive? What output are you receiving instead?

Comment: @MadPhysicist sir i want the creted date and last access/modified date of that files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine file creation date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723838/determine-file-creation-date-in-java)

Comment: @crush i am getting all the files of desktop as output(even though the files are in folder)
and also the created date and access date of that file,
and my main problem statement is 
Write a program to identify the least used icons/files/folders on the desktop and move them to temp folder created in Documents.

Comment: @Roshan, isn't that what you are trying to do? You should really clarify your expected output in the question.