# How can I find deployment date of war file, deployed at weblogic server

Tags: java, maven, deployment, war, weblogic-10.x

I have to show deployment date of application in report generated by application for that I have to fetch **deployment date of war file using java code**. How can I fetch the deployment date of application(.war) using Java code. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

using JDK 7 you can read the file attributes like the creation date,so reading the file attributes of the war file should serve the purpose.

Please,refer
 [Determine file creation date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723838/determine-file-creation-date-in-java)

Comment: I think you need to connect server for determining creation date of war file.

Comment: KDP: for that we have to find deployment path, but that will not be accessible for every user which could be cause of access exceptions. Any other way?

Comment: the other way would be provide some web service or a method so the users can call and get the required info.