# How to read various file properties java

Tags: java, file-io, file-properties

I have a file with extension .ivt. I have to get description and summary of the file. Everything is stored in file properties. It contains the author, description and date of creation. I looked all over the internet and did not find any code that can do that. Is there any way I can extract that information from the file using java?

Comment: I just want file properties like author name, file description written by the author, date created, etc using java

Comment: Check out [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723838/determine-file-creation-date-in-java) as what you are asking could very well be OS specific.

Comment: Thanks for this but, I want more advance information that is specific to the file like description written by the author

Answer (score 0):

```
public class File{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("/tmp");
    FileOwnerAttributeView ownerAttributeView = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, FileOwnerAttributeView.class);
    UserPrincipal owner = ownerAttributeView.getOwner();
    System.out.println("owner: " + owner.getName());
  }
}
```

This gets you details like create, file date, etc.: `

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(path.getInputStream()));
String data ="";
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    data = br.readLine();
}
System.out.println("Extracted value : " + data);
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data);
String date = st.nextToken();//Get date
String time = st.nextToken();//Get time
System.out.println("Creation Date  : " + date);
System.out.println("Creation Time  : " + time);
```

Comment: Yeah I want to read file properties like author name, description, date created using java

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.