# How to poll file from folder in FIFO order

Tags: java, file, java-8, java-7

How to poll file from folder which copied/placed first ("FIFO" order)

scenario: if i placed 10 file in folder. how do i get first came inside the folder ("FIFO")

Comment: note that on linux [not all filesystems record the creation time](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7562). You may want to encode that information in some meta file or the filenames instead or consider using one of the other times, such as last modified.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you want to get the files and sort them by creation time. You can do this using `Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime()`. See [`BasicFileAttributes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) documentation for details.

```
public Stream<Path> filesByCreation(Path folder) throws IOException {
    return Files.list(folder).sorted(
           Comparator.comparing((Path path) -> {
               try {
                   return Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class)
                               .creationTime();
               } catch(IOException ex) {
                   throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
               }
           }));
}
```

Usage:

```
filesByCreation(Paths.get("/path/to/my/folder")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would get a File::listFiles() and then write a comparator that will sort these files based on their created time.
The files time can be access using this : [Determine file creation date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723838/determine-file-creation-date-in-java)

Edit:
This assumes that while copying/moving the files into this folder the created/updated timestamps are not preserved.