# Getting date/time of creation of a file

Tags: java, file, date, properties

This seems like a pretty straightforward question but I haven't been able to find a definitive answer anywhere online. How can I get the date/time a file was created through Java's file manager? Aside from just the name of a file, what else can I get about the file's "properties"?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723838/determine-file-creation-date-in-java

Comment: did you check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586/how-to-discover-a-files-creation-time-with-java ?

Comment: Hmmm, @jt, I must have overlooked that. You should consider just putting it as your answer, that link pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get creation date of a file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741466/how-to-get-creation-date-of-a-file-in-java)

Comment: @AeroDroid - it will get closed as duplicate.

Comment: But remember that most Linux filesystems [don't support file creation timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure how you'd get it using Java 6 and below. With Java 7's new file system APIs, it'd look like this:

```
Path path = ... // the path to the file
BasicFileAttributes attributes = 
    Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
FileTime creationTime = attributes.creationTime();
```

As CoolBeans said, not all file systems store the creation time. The [BasicFileAttributes Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) states:

> If the file system implementation does not support a time stamp to indicate the time when the file was created then this method returns an implementation specific default value, typically the last-modified-time or a FileTime representing the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

Comment: Hmm, well I think I'll go with jt's answer. That worked for me.

Comment: that seems horrible to return default values like that. Who created this API? What was their reasoning?

Comment: @bblfish: It seems to me that there isn't much potential harm from returning a default value for something like the creation time. It simplifies the API and allows code working with attributes to just treat all `BasicFileAttributes` the same without worrying about whether or not one specific attribute isn't supported by the underlying file system.

Comment: Is there a non nio way to get creation time?

Comment: @KMP: You can perhaps call a system function like `stat`, but no, not with the `File` API.