# Listing files in the order in which they were created in folder

Tags: java, file, io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the last modified file in a directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064694/how-do-i-find-the-last-modified-file-in-a-directory-in-java)

I am trying to retrieve files from a directory in the order in which they were created. This has become an issue using Java. The listFiles() method in the File class does not guarantee an order in which the files are returned. Are there any other ways of retrieving the files by the order in which they were created in the directory?

Comment: OP is looking for *creation time*, not *modification time*. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to sort your `array of files` returned by `File.listFiles()` using a `Comparator` on the basis of [`File.lastModified`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29)

Comment: Just beat me to it! Only works if the files have not been modified since creation, of course...

Comment: I am already doing that, is the last modified date a reliable source for created date when files are being ftp'd to this folder?

Comment: What is `ftp'd`? And did you try using it? Is it giving you correct result?

Comment: My program monitors a folder and needs to process the files in FIFO order. The files are transferred to that folder via File Transfer Protocol (FTP)

Comment: @ReidMac. In that case, you would have to use the `creation time`. Modified time will not work for newly created files.

Comment: @ReidMac. Check [Files.readAttributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAttributes%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) and [BasicFileAttributes.creationTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#creationTime%28%29) for this purpose.

Comment: I have to use Java 6. Java 7 is not an option.

Comment: [This](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-file-creation-date-in-java/) may be useful

Comment: Yes sorting is not the problem. The problem is that files are being constantly added to this folder 24 hours a day 7 days a week. Whenever I retrieve files using the listFiles() method, is it possible that File A was inserted into the folder first, but not even retrieved using the listFiles() method while other files are retrieved, which were added later?

Comment: It also needs to be OS independent.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not, but the [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) method does take a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). I've defined a simple one for you below and knock yourself out:

```
new Comparator<File>() {
public int compare(File m1, File  m2) {
    return m1.lastModified().compare(m2.lastModified());
}
});
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Create A `Set<File>` unsorted where you add all the `File`s (`unsorted.addAll(dir.listFiles()`)
Then, create a new `TreeSet` using `Set<File> sorted=new TreeSet(Comparator<File> byDate)` with a custom comparator comparing the dates.

```
Comparator<File> byDate=new Comparator<File>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        return new Date(o1.lastModified()).compareTo(new Date(o2.lastModified()));
    }
};
```

and do:

```
sorted.addAll(unsorted);
```

The new 
Set will be ordered by date.

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out `listFiles` does not guarantee and order. As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885269/getting-date-time-of-creation-of-a-file) you can get its attributes to find creation time and use something like [thia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203030/best-way-to-list-files-in-java-sorted-by-date-modified) to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the Java API for [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), there's a method called `lastModified`. If you sort the files by that attribute you should get what you wanted. I'm pretty sure there's no way to arrange files after their creation, since each implementation is OS specific.

So if you made a comparator like so:

```
public class FileComparator implements Comparator<File> {
  public int compare(File x, File y) {
    Long.compare(x.lastModified(), y.lastModified());
  }
}
```

It can be used like so:

```
File file = new File("...");
List<File> files = Arrays.asList(file.listFiles());
Collections.sort(files, new FileComparator());
```