# How to get proper file creation date of file?

Tags: java, file

I need not last modification time and not last file accessed time, but file creation time. I have not found information about this. Maybe some libs?

```
Path p = Paths.get(f.getAbsoluteFile().toURI());
BasicFileAttributes view = null;
try {
    view = Files.getFileAttributeView(p,
                            BasicFileAttributeView.class).readAttributes();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
FileTime creationTime = view.creationTime();
```

In this code creation time is not valid and return today date.

Operation System: Windows 7
Java: SE-1.7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As yshavit said, not all operating systems record the date created. However, you should be able to use `java.nio.file` to determine this information on operating systems that do have this functionality - see the documentation for [`files.getAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) - note that [`BasicFileAttributeView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributeView.html) has a field for `creationTime`.

You can use `FileSystems.getDefault();` to determine what `FileAttributeView`s are supported on the current operating system.

`Files.getAttribute(path, "basic:createdAt");` will return a `FileTime` object with the date the file was created on a system that supports `BasicFileAttributeView`. You'll have to convert it to a `java.util.Date` object, but I'll let you figure that out on your own.

### Further Reading

- NIO [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getAttribute%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) for `getAttribute()`
- NIO [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributeView.html) for `BasicFileAttributeView`
- A [tutorial](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-file-basic-attributes/) for using `readAttributes()`
- A comprehensive [tutorial](http://andreinc.net/2013/12/05/java-7-nio-2-tutorial-file-attributes/) on using FileAttributes
- Another StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885269/getting-date-time-of-creation-of-a-file) on the same topic

Answer (score 6):

How to get the creation date of a file in `Java`, using [**`BasicFileAttributes`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) class, this is an example:

```
   Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\jorgesys\\workspaceJava\\myfile.txt");
    BasicFileAttributes attr;
    try {
    attr = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);

    System.out.println("Creation date: " + attr.creationTime());

    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("oops error! " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to do this across all systems, since not all systems even record that information. Linux doesn't, for instance; see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842195/how-to-get-file-creation-date-time-in-bash-debian).

Many programs "modify" a file by copying it, making a change on the copy, and then moving the copy to the original file's location. So for those, there's not a meaningful distinction between creation and last-modification.