# How can i get the Created Date and Time of a file in java?

Tags: java, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to discover a File's creation time with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586/how-to-discover-a-files-creation-time-with-java)

I want to get created date and time of file in java.
How can i do it ?

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741466/how-to-get-creation-date-of-a-file-in-java

Comment: @ptomil for this i have to add extra library which is not my requirment.thsnks for reply. But is there any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

[How to get the file creation date in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-file-creation-date-in-java/)

Comment: i have tried it but its not giving correct value.

Comment: +1 its working now. its needed some changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have ***cmd /c dir fileName*** command for doing this :

Try using

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process output = runtime.exec("cmd /c dir "+fname);
```

Process the output of runtime and get the desired stamp.

Comment: i have pass through this logic but its not working properly.this logic gives same date and time for every file.